# how to write shell script to copy files in the same directory where the script is present

Tags: linux, shell

I am running a shell script say xyz.sh. This shell script need to copy all files present in the same directory where this script is present to some another folder. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
TARGETDIR='z';for file in *;do test "$file" != "$TARGETDIR" && cp -r "$file" "$TARGETDIR/";done
```

Comment: That will also copy the script to TARGETDIR.  I guess that may not be what the OP expects.

Comment: The op did say anything :)

Comment: My question is ... suppose xyz.sh is in dir ABC. now i can run xyz.sh by giving 
sh ABC/xyz.sh
now i want to copy all files in ABC to another folder along with xyz.sh

Location of target directory I know, but location of ABC is unknown.

Comment: this will copy from current dir, but not from where script is placed

Answer (score 1):

You should determine dir, where script is placed if you run it not from it's own dir. So, it will looks like:

```
cp `dirname $0`/* /path/to/newdir/
```

Now if you call script, `dirname $0` will give you base path of where script is placed and cp will copy everything from this path to new location.

Comment: can you tell me 1 more thing....how to write a command name to file, not the output of the command but the command name

Comment: I do not understand question. Describe please.